# Alter authorize.net transaction key dynamically?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, authorize.net

I am currently building an ecommerce website that is used for 5 separate companies using woocommerce and `authorize.net` for the payment.

So far the authorization is working great for a single vendor, the issue comes in that once I have selected the vendor by location, I need to change the `api_transaction_key` and `api_login_id` to the correct vendor before payment is processed.

I have been searching the files for hours now and cannot find where the key and id are set.

Can someone help me find where I can overwrite the key and id values to what I need?
or would it be better to create a new payment gateway for each of the vendors and copy all of the `authorize.net` gateway information except the key and id?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This answer is here for if anyone is curious on how I was able to make this work.
in the Authorize.net woocommerce payment gateway you'll find a file called

> class-wc-authorize-net-cim-api.php

and it is in this file's contruct function that your hook needs to be placed.

```
public function __construct( $api_user_id, $api_transaction_key, $environment ) {
    // File default code
    }
```

This needs the follow three lines of code to be placed BEFORE the default file code

> ```
> $custom_auth_info = apply_filters('get_custom_auth', $custom_auth_info );   
> $api_user_id = $custom_auth_info['api_user_id'];
> $api_transaction_key = $custom_auth_info['api_transaction_key'];
> ```

The apply_filters refers to the following function that is placed in my plugin

```
add_filter('get_custom_auth', 'select_distributor_by_state');

function select_distributor_by_state($custom_auth_info = []) {
    global $wpdb;

   //Your Query is here to select the proper distributor from the DB
   //and retrieve their custom Authorize.net ID and Transaction Key

    $custom_auth_info['api_user_id'] = $your_query[0]['api_loginid'];
    $custom_auth_info['api_transaction_key'] = $your_query[0]['api_transactionkey'];
    $_SESSION['dealer'] = $vendor[0]['id'];
    return $custom_auth_info;
}
```

This filter allows you to hook in, grab the data you need, then return it and apply it directly into the code before the payment is processed.

Comment: I don't like this solution as it requires modifying the plugin's code. These changes will be lost whenever the plugin is updated. Ideally I'd be looking for a solution that uses filters built into the plugin.

Comment: @Skcorroh This solution doesn't work anymore. Do you have any updates related to it?

Comment: @AshleyStrout you are totally right, funny enough I posted this question just 2 months into my working as a developer. I had no idea what I was doing.

Comment: @Jordan Unfortunately I don't have any updates for you, this was for a website at a job I haven't worked at in 7 years. I haven't seen that code in ages. Good luck though!